# Share to facebook not working on device but working on desktop (HTML5 app)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, facebook

I've built an android application using HTML5. In the desktop version, the dialog feed of facebook shows up properly when my share button is clicked. But when I installed it to my device and click the share button, the dialog feed won't just show up. What's the problem? Is the jQuery code different when calling the feed dialog on browsers than in mobile?

Edit:

Initializing facebook sdk:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
    $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function(){
        FB.init({
            appId: XXXXXXXXXX,
            version: 'v2.3' // or v2.0, v2.1, v2.0
        });     
        $('#loginbutton,#feedbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(){
            alert('Status updated!!');
        });
    });
})
```

facebook share button is clicked:

```
$scope.shareToFacebook = function() {
      FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'feed',
            link: 'http://mydomainhere',
            description: 'myDescriptionHere',
        },
            // callback
            function(response) {
                /*if (response && !response.error_message) {
                    alert('Posting completed.');
                    } 
                else {
                    alert('Error while posting.');
                }*/
            }
        );
  };
```

Comment: @SnailArt Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, show us some code, and tell us what you've tried so far, so we can help you better!

Comment: sorry about that.. I edited my question. It's perfectly working fine when on browsers.. the problem is when I build the app as an apk file, the button does not show the dialog feed.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i got that problem a time , all i had to do is to install the InAppBrowser Plugin

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser